# Rails 3: Excluding Results by Default

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

On my site, moderators can flag spammy comments. When these comments are flagged, they get quarantined so they no longer appear in regular views, though they can still be seen in the administrative control panel. At the moment, I exclude them from regular views like so:

```
@comments = Comment.where(:flagged => false)
```

I do this in every controller that has comments in it, of which there are many. I get the feeling that there's a cleaner way to handle this in Rails. Perhaps somewhere in the comments model I can specify that when querying for comments, only retrieve those that aren't flagged. If so, how is that done? And even if that's not possible, is there some other way to dry this code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

u can use a default scope

```
default_scope where(:flagged => false)
```

see http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/default_scope/class

the default scope can be ignored using **unscoped**. See http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/unscoped/class

i would prefer using a scope rather a default scope since i dont have to override it when all the records are needed. Depends upon the frequency of fetching all/unflagged records.

Comment: This is the right idea, but your code is incorrect. It should simply be: `default_scope where(:flagged => false)`. Where did you get `unflagged` from??

Comment: In this case, there are 4 views that would use the default scope and 1 view that would exclude it. Seems like defaulting is the more efficient approach, unless there's something I'm unaware of.

Comment: i actually wanted to write a scope flagged but then changed my mind to using default scope since its better on the normal user side(admin has few views, mostly)

Answer (score 2):

Make a scope (named 'clean' for this example):

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord
  scope :clean, where(:flagged => false)
end
```

Then use:

```
@comments = Comment.clean
```

For future-proofing, you may may want to add a class method called `default_view` which just calls `clean` and use that instead.  As your 'default' needs change, just modify the `default_view` method.